# Where does the metadata come from in .NET (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I thought I knew the answer to this, I understood it to be from the referenced library via reflection.  However, I have a situation where I'm trying to debug a C# program, using a second reference program, written in VB.NET (that is, I'm trying to re-write the VB.NET program in C#).

The specific code that I'm looking at uses a referenced class, and F12 (go to definition) for my C# program loads the object metadata in a new window; however the same action in the VB.NET program takes me to the object browser, claiming the referenced dll is located somewhere different (they both reference the same libraries).

Is it possible that the two languages behave differently in such a central aspect, or is there another part to referencing a library that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Probably what's happening is that the C# program is referencing the DLL in a directory where the PDB is also located.  The debugger is loading the PDB, and therefore knows where the source files are on the local machine. The same isn't going on for the VB program.  Or, perhaps, you have a plugin that disassembles for you, and it only works with C# applications.  Visual studio doesn't disassemble jack.

Comment: Your confusing assembly metadata and debug information. Metadata is loaded for both - it's always loaded. It's a fundamental part of a CLI assembly.

Comment: The directories of the referenced assemblies do not have PDB files.  Also, this is as design time (i.e. hitting F12 while the program is not running).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go To Definition can only take you to the actual source code when the IDE knows about that code and IntelliSense has parsed it.  Which it can't do if the project is not a part of the same solution or not written in the same language.  An assembly reference only provides the metadata that's embedded in the assembly.  Which just describes the type, not the code.  There is no link to the original source code that generated it, other than through the debugger's PDB file which IntelliSense doesn't use since it can't be relied on to be present and accurate.

And yes, the C# IDE and the VB.NET IDE use different ways to solve that problem.  Otherwise a side-effect of having two very different teams that worked on it and a lack of commonality in their IDE evolution.  Visual Basic has had IDE support for many decades, C# was the new kid on the block and the team behind it needed to start from scratch 13 years ago.

The VB.NET IDE indeed highlights the identifier in the Object Browser, the way it was done 15+ years ago.  The C# IDE has code that decompiles the assembly metadata back to readable C# code and shows the resulting text in an editor window.  Exactly why the C# team didn't choose the VB.NET approach is surely only known by insiders.