# VS classes are empty?

Tags: visual-studio

So I wanted to see how a class was implemented by pressing F12. When I did this, it showed the class with all it's methods hidden. But when I press en + sign, all that is shown is the documentation for it, not the actual implementation. Why is this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can only see the source code if you have the .cs files for this project.  Failing that, VS can only decompile the declarations from the metadata in the assembly.  And annotate them with the IntelliSense info from the .xml file.  Contact the author of the library, he might be willing to share the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19252050/6909765) for the reason of this behavior.

**Essentially, if you are trying to browse the code of a dll, this is the expected behavior.**

From your question, it is not known whether you are trying to browse code local to your solution, or 3rd party code, but I am guessing it is 3rd party code.

You can also use a tool like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to view the decompiled code of a dll without having the original source.